# PHP form validation not functioning

Tags: php, validation

I just started learning PHP and already encountered my first annoying obstacle.

I'm just creating a simple registration form, but the validation doesn't seem to notify an error when fields are empty, and redirects to the next page.
I checked the validation code with die; just to make sure it runs, and it does, but for some reason it's not doing anything about it.

I'm sure there may be more questions regarding this problem, I just couldn't find an answer that fits my case.

I appreciate your time reading and/or answering! (:

index.php :

```
<html>
<?php require 'validation.php'; ?>

<div class="container" >
<form class="reg-table" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars('welcome.php');?>">

  <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstName"> First Name : </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName">
        <span class="error"><?php echo $firstNameErr;?></span>
    </div>
```

validation.php :

```
    <?php

    $firstNameErr = "";
    $firstName = "";


    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

if (empty($_POST["firstName"])) {
        $firstNameErr = "Name is required";
      } else {
        $firstName = $_POST["firstName"];
      }
```

welcome.php :

```
<html>
<?php require 'validation.php';
$firstNameErr = "";
$firstName = "";?>
<body>
Welcome <?php echo $_POST["firstName"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars('welcome.php');?>"` look at that very closely and look at what that produces in the HTML source.

Comment: You are not printing the error anywhere nor stopping the execution of your script when there is an error. What is your desired outcome?

Comment: You're clobbering the `$firstNameErr` variable after you include the `require 'validation.php';`

Comment: you're clearing variable values after require, `$firstNameErr = "";
$firstName = "";`

Comment: we also don't know if you even closed off the form tag.

Comment: answerers should pay more attention to detail here.

Comment: Either you didn't paste the entire `validation.php` file, or you have a syntax error there - there's no closing brace for `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")`.

Comment: I'm very confused as to what this code is trying to achieve. `validation.php` does things(perhaps) but you're just using `$_POST` anyway

Comment: `Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>` => `Your email address is: undefined index email` - given what you posted.

Comment: I'm with @apokryfos ... this code makes no sense its intent. It does something for index.php, but the welcome.php has no use? Why include it?

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the values immediately in welcome.php:

```
<?php require 'validation.php';
$firstNameErr = "";
$firstName = "";?>
```

That equates to:

```
<?php 
    require 'validation.php';
    $firstNameErr = "";
    $firstName = "";

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        if (empty($_POST["firstName"])) {
            $firstNameErr = "Name is required";
        } else {
            $firstName = $_POST["firstName"];
        }
    }
    $firstNameErr = "";
    $firstName = "";?>
```

Also, there are no special chars in `welcome.php`, so you dont need that function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in `welcome.php`. You are clearing the variables after `require`.

```
<html>
    <?php require 'validation.php'; ?>

    <body>
        Welcome <?php echo $_POST["firstName"]; ?><br>
        Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think that

```
htmlspecialchars('welcome.php')
```

Can be causing an issue here. If the validation code is the same address where the form is, you can just leave this argument empty (action='').

More than that, I think you've just made a simple thing very complicated. Once you change your form's *action* attribute to empty, you can just process the form on the same page where your form is. Eg:

```
if(isset($_POST['YOUR-SUBMIT-NAME-HERE']))
    require 'validation.php';
else
    require 'your-form.php';
```

But to make it really good-looking and easy to update in the future, you could read some tutorials about good practicies handling forms in PHP and get interested into AJAX. Good luck and cheers!

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you are redirecting to `welcome.php` before validating your form on `index.php`.

Since you want to display the error in your `index.php` page, you should not allow the form to leave the current page until the validation is successful. So, the form action should point to the current page (`index.php`). You can do this by setting `action="."`. Then, in your `index.php` file provide some validation and redirect to the `welcome.php` page if there are no validation issues.

```
// ... Other index.php logic ...

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    if (empty($_POST["firstName"])) {
        $firstNameErr = "Name is required";
    } else {
        // Redirect to the welcome page.
        header('location: welcome.php?firstName='.$_POST['firstName']);
    }
}

// ... Other index.php logic ...
```